# Emotions VS Maslow pyramid

Tags: emotion

Where are the emotions in the [Maslow pyramid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs)?

[image]

When we go from inside of [basic emotions](https://www.psychologytoday.com/hk/blog/hide-and-seek/201601/what-are-basic-emotions?amp) outside like this:

[image]

in which direction at the Maslow pyramid we would move?

***Update:***

Based on ***@ArnonWeinberg*** Comment i need to  mention these information about my prose of asking this question:

> I like to have one theory about this relations between the Psychology
>   emotional growing and the Maslow pyramid levels, so i asked this kind,
>   but could be another Emotional diagram which is more Updated

new Update:

i found this paper which is saying about computational mode of Emotions:

[The Relationship Between Emotion Models and Artificial Intelligence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.09554.pdf)

and [this](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20120313163017001-153025.pdf) power-point:

[image]

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I'm not clear on why you think these theories would be connected?  Also, please note that both are long outdated, and no longer taken seriously in mainstream science.

Comment: I like to have one theory about this relations between the Psychology emotional growing and the Maslow pyramid levels, so i asked this kind, but could be another Emotional diagram which is more Updated.

Answer (score 3):

The 2 concepts you are referring to are Maslow’s hierarchy of needs ([Maslow, 1943](https://scottbarrykaufman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Maslow-1943.pdf)) and Plutchik’s general psychoevolutionary theory of emotion ([Plutchik, 1980](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Ie1GBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3)). **They are totally separate concepts**, but can be **linked only to a small degree**.

As someone progress within Maslow’s hierarchy of needs, the person can experience a variety of different emotions, depending on their experiences leading up to and upon achieving that level of attainment.

For example, someone who has met all their safety needs may experience a sense of optimism and trust in their environment. When meeting their love and relationship needs there will probably be experiences of love, but also there may be joy and serenity.

If for some reason the person loses an aspect or more of their safety needs, for example, there could be apprehension, worry, fear, annoyance, pensiveness...

### References

Maslow, A. H. (1943). A theory of human motivation. *Psychological review, 50*(4), 370-396. doi: [10.1037/h0054346](https://doi.org/10.1037/h0054346) Free PDF: https://scottbarrykaufman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Maslow-1943.pdf

Plutchik, R. (1980). A general psychoevolutionary theory of emotion. In *Theories of emotion* (pp. 3-33). Academic press. doi: [10.1016/B978-0-12-558701-3.50007-7](https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-558701-3.50007-7) Google Books: https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Ie1GBQAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA3